# Relation between closed graph theorem and uniform boundedness principle

Tags: functional-analysis

I asked a question few days back whether it is possible to prove closed graph theorem (CGT) from uniform boundedness principle (UBP). One comment guided me to [this](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/190587/is-there-a-simple-direct-proof-of-the-open-mapping-theorem-from-the-uniform-boun) question whose answer has provided the proof of open mapping theorem (OMT) using UBP, from which it follows that we can also prove CGT from UBP as CGT can be proved using OMT. But my professor said that it is not the case. And he has asked to find the example when UBP actually fails to imply CGT. I am little confuse now. I read the proof given there of UBP implies OMT and I understood it fully. But is it something that is not as trivial as it look in that proof or is there something hidden in the proof that is something extra assumption which makes the implication possible. I didn't find anything such but if there is, can someone please point it out. Also I would like to have some hint regarding the example when UBP fails to imply CGT if there is one. The statements of CGT and UBP I am using are as follows.

Closed graph theorem says ' A closed operator between Banach spaces is continuous'.

Principle of uniform boundedness says ' If $V$ is Banach and $W$ is a normed space, then pointwise bounded family of continuous operators between them is uniformly bounded.'

Comment: Did you show the proof given in that answer or the reference given in the comments to your professor? Unless there is some missing detail or context you do not give it seems your professor is mistaken.

Comment: Ok..I will have a chat with him and then update the missing details.

Comment: @ Rhys Steele I have two small queries. Can you please take a look. 1. At the end of the answer, there is one remark that both PUB and OMT are equivalent to being barreled. Does this mean that we can replace the completeness condition on the target space in OMT and completeness condition on the domain space in PUB by the barreled space condition and can still prove the one via other.

Comment: 2.  Then is it the case with PUB and CGT also i.e.  is PUB and CGT are also equivalent to being barreled. Right now, the proof I am having of OMT implies CGT uses the completeness of target space. That's why this query. Thanks.

Comment: I suggest you look at the reference given in the comment at the mathoverflow question. It gives precise statements for those things.